# How to monitor local Postgres Datebase

Tags: database, postgresql, monitor

For my project I am trying to hit my Postgres database and monitor the uptime, status etc. I have looked around and the only thing that is not an external tool is the statistics collector, but I am not sure that is the correct one. Any ideas on how to do the monitoring I need without using external sources?

Comment: Did you check out the various [monitoring views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring.html)  and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) e.g. The uptime can be queried using `select current_timestamp - pg_postmaster_start_time()`